# Why does Jesus say "Call no man your father upon the earth"

Tags: bible

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Are there any Christian groups that follow Matthew 23:9?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/are-there-any-christian-groups-that-follow-matthew-239)
>   [What is the Roman Catholic view on Matthew 23:9?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4409/what-is-the-roman-catholic-view-on-matthew-239/4412#4412)

> Matthew 23:9
>
> And call no man your father upon the earth: for one is your Father,
>   which is in heaven.

In human life, it's usual to be attached to one's parents and for parents to be proud of their children (especially when they're young) to the point of vanity.

I'm a bit confused or rather conflicted by the message or intent of this line or am I interpreting it incorrectly?

Comment: Related: [What is the Roman Catholic view on Matthew 23:9?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4409/what-is-the-roman-catholic-view-on-matthew-239) and [Are there any Christian groups that follow Matthew 23:9?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4502/are-there-any-christian-groups-that-follow-matthew-239)

Comment: Hi JoseK, welcome to Christianity StackExchange. There are a wide variety of groups within Christianity that will interpret any one Bible verse somewhat differently. To answer your question it would help to focus it a bit more - is there any particular point of view you're seeking an answer from?